# Angular *ngIf check if element currently getting shown on page or not

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

*ngIf check if element currently getting shown on page or not.

I have two *sibling* component. Component **A** having a some text value say '**SOME_TEXT**'
Now in html of Component **B**, I need check for span element.

If '**SOME_TEXT**' is getting shown currently on page/app then *ngIf should be **false**. Meaning span tag in component **B** should NOT be shown.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this. ?

Thanks.

Comment: This question pertains more to JavaScript and HTML than it does Angular.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the question, but I think you could use DOM to get the element in component A at somewhere of component B's script.
For example, inside component B's `ngOnInit` get some value from

```
document.getElementById("id in A html")
```

or

Use Service and power of Observable

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TextService {

  textObserver: Observer<string>|undefined
  text: Observable<string> = new Observable()

  updateText(val: string) {
    
    if (!this.textObserver) {
      this.text = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
        this.textObserver = observer
        this.textObserver.next(val)
      })
      this.text.subscribe()
      return;
    }
    this.textObserver?.next(val)
  }

}
```

In somewhere of component A you can call `updateText` to set text and in component B you can do `this.textService.text.subscribe(text => // your code)` to get text and use in html view